# Setting global variable not working in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I could not access `$result` outside the `foreach` loop. When I use `dump($results);` inside the loop I'm getting result, but when I'm using `dump($results);` outside the loop result is empty.

```
$results = array();

foreach ($menu as $menus) {
    $mid = $menus->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();

    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT s.subtitle,m.* FROM submenu as s,menu as m where s.menu_id=m.id and m.id=:data");
    $statement->bindValue('data', $mid);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll();
}
dump($results)
```

Comment: Are you sure `$menu` has anything in it?

Comment: It seems like your variables in the `foreach` may be backwards. The name `$menus` sounds like the name of an array, while `$menu` would be an element of the array.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to prepare the statement in the loop. Prepare it once, use `bindParam` to bind the parameter to a variable reference, then set the variable and call `execute()` in the loop.

Comment: Well, you overwrite it each time anyway, maybe you want `$results[] = $statement->fetchAll();`

Comment: yes I have a array of 4 data in '$menu' and I'm trying to print all data associated with ''$menu''

Comment: @AbrCadaver Thank you very much .It is working now after using $result[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the `$results` variable each time through the loop. So the final value will just be the result of the last query. I suspect you want to combine the results of all the queries, so you need to merge the arrays.

Change

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

to:

```
$result += $statement->fetchAll();
```

Alternatively you could just combine all the queries into a single query. Put all the menu IDs into an array `$menuIDs`, and do:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.subtitle,m.* FROM submenu as s,menu as m where s.menu_id=m.id and m.id IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($menuIDs), '?')) . ")";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($menuIDs);
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```